# Consecutive integers which are products of Fibonacci numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, recurrences, multiplicative-number-theory

Let $F_1, F_2, \dots$ be the sequence of Fibonacci numbers, and let $\mathcal{M}$ be the set of positive integers expressible as a product of Fibonacci numbers (OEIS [A065108](http://oeis.org/A065108)).

One can prove that
$$F_{2n}F_{2n+2} = F_{2n+1}^2 - 1 = F_{2n-1}F_{2n+3} - 2 ,$$
which implies that there exist infinitely many 3-tuple of consecutive integers all of them belonging to $\mathcal{M}$.

**Questions:** Do there exist infinitely many 4-tuple of consecutive integers belonging to $\mathcal{M}$ ? What about $k$-tuples for $k > 4$ ?

An inspection of the first 10,000 elements of $\mathcal{M}$ yields only the following runs of four consecutive integers in $\mathcal{M}$:

$$(1, 2, 3, 4); (2, 3, 4, 5); (3, 4, 5, 6); (24, 25, 26, 27),$$

In the same range, the 5-tuples of consecutive integers in $\mathcal{M}$ are:

$$(1, 2, 3, 4, 5); (2, 3, 4, 5, 6) ,$$

and the only 6-tuple is $(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)$. I found no 7-tuple.

Comment: If a Fibonacci number is divisible by 7, then it is divisible by 3. Hence $k=14$ is impossible.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov nice observation. Indeed 7 is the smallest prime we can play this trick with.